# How do I pull price from HTML using VBA?

Tags: html, vba

I am new to VBA in Excel and am having problems trying to pull a price from HTML. Any help would be appreciated!

I am getting a Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
`Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlprices As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlprice As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://www.txsmartbuy.com/product/10377318"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set htmldoc = ie.Document
Set htmlprice = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("txcpa-itemDetails").Item(1).innerText

MsgBox htmlprice

End Sub`
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Error?  No results?

Comment: htmlPrice is presumably not an object and you are using .innerText accessor. Remove the SET keyword which is for object references and declare as appropriate type.

Comment: I'm getting a Run-time error '91'. Not sure what to declare htmlprice as to get a result

Comment: Declare as string as you are retrieving .innerText